# Two the same subqueries in query - how to make them 1?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have table places

```
place_id | city | country_code | zipcode | lat | lon
```

Now I want to show places that are within 25 miles of place A. Place A has place_id 1.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `places` 
WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians((SELECT lat FROM places WHERE place_id=1)) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians((SELECT lon FROM places WHERE place_id=1)) ) + sin( radians((SELECT lat FROM places WHERE place_id=1)) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < 25;
```

This works ok, but there are two the same subqueries

```
SELECT lat FROM places WHERE place_id=1
```

Is it possible to optimize this query to not have two the same subqueries but make them into 1?

Comment: If you want to hear one of those "MySQL never gets the good-stuff" comments: look into "Common table expressions" or CTE, they are available in MSSQL and Oracle - they are sweet-sweet syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three subqueries will execute for every row in the outer table.

What you can do is convert those subqueries to a single `JOIN` which will only execute once for the entire query in order to find the latitude and longitude of `place_id 1`:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   places a
JOIN   (SELECT lat, lon FROM places WHERE place_id = 1) b ON
       (3959 * acos( cos( radians(b.lat) ) * cos( radians( a.lat ) ) * cos( radians( a.lon ) - radians(b.lon) ) + sin( radians(b.lat) ) * sin( radians( a.lat ) ) ) ) < 25;
```

Comment: tnx, I didn't know I can use join in such way.

Answer (score 0):

Derive a new table from the subquery and make join with the original table, like

```
SELECT *
FROM places p, (SELECT lat AS new_lat FROM places WHERE place_id = 1) l
WHERE blah blah
```

now you can replace the subquery with column 'new_lat'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable `@var_lon` to cache output of query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `places`
WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians((SELECT lat FROM places WHERE place_id=1)) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians((SELECT @var_lon := lon FROM places WHERE place_id=1)) ) + sin( radians(@var_lon) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < 25;
```